# Change cursor in OSX app

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm trying to change the cursor in an OS X app with the following code (copied from Xcode docs):

```
NSCursor* c = [NSCursor pointingHandCursor]; [c set];
```

It is not taking effect and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

On an NSView you can try

```
- (void)resetCursorRects {
    [super resetCursorRects];
    [self addCursorRect:[self bounds] cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];
}
```

This should work also on NSWIndow but I have not not tested